# cycle types of all words in a permutation group

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutations, permutation-groups

I have been working with permutation groups. For a given $G\subset S_n$, what I have been computing depends only on the conjugacy class of $G$.

Say all permutation groups in this question are generated by two elements, always called $x$ and $y$. I wrote a lot of computer code, and it turned out to be very convenient and memory efficient to work with the cycle types of a few elements given by certain short words -- say, for each $G$ I would systematically have a look at the cycle types of $x$, $y$, $xy$, $xyx$ and $yxy$ (in truth it was more complicated, but whatever). And for many questions I could forget about $G$ itself and only consider the cycle types.

It worked like a charm, and even though I clearly got lucky with the type of things I was trying to compute, I have been impressed, and cannot help wondering: is there any literature about the map defined on $F_2$, the free group on $X$ and $Y$, which takes a word $w$ to the cycle type of $w(x,y)\in S_n$ ?

I know that one can sometimes find, for a fixed $G$, two homomorphisms $G\to S_n$ that are pointwise-conjugate but not conjugate, so one cannot have unreasonable hopes. Still, if anything interesting has been proved about the map, I would love to know.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$? Are they a transposition and an $n$-cycle?

Comment: @will: i mean this in complete generality. Pick $x$ and $y$, look at the group $G$ they generate. Or rather, look at the corresponding map from $F_2$ to the set of all possible cycle types. I don't know what to expect, really; it's just been surprisingly effective to look at this, for some very special computations.

Comment: It could be relevant that two random permutations $x,y \in S_n$ generate $A_n$ or $S_n$ with probability approaching $1$ as $n \to \infty$. So your map is likely to be surjective with probability nearly $3/4$.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://zbmath.org/1297.05107 We use an idea which is a little bit similar -- we show that if you pick a couple of elements $a,b\in S_n$ whose supports are not too large, then there is a word $w(a,b)$ whose support is strictly smaller with positive probability. When I say "there is a word", I mean that we took specific words (like the commutator) and showed that this result holds for each specific word for different definitions of *not too large*.